# Change Css File Depending On Browser Height

Tags: css, window

Can I change which CSS file is loaded depending on the height of the browser?

For example, if the browser is less than 600px then use index_sm.css but use index_lg.css otherwise.

Comment: Are you trying to see if the user is on a mobile device?

Comment: No, i have a footer at the bottom of my page and it is positioned absolute bottom 0 but if the screen is too small it overlaps page content so when the screen is smaller i position the footer from the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `<head>` tags, put the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.innerHeight <= 600) {
        loadcss('index_sm.css');
    } else {
        loadcss('index_lg.css');
    }

    function loadcss(file) {
        var el = document.createElement('link');
        el.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
        el.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        el.setAttribute('href', file);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Note that this only works if Javascript is enabled, thus if someone is using noscript or browsing from a javascript disabled browser, it won't work.

Comment: Screen height is not browser height

Comment: I just realized that this does not work in IE, when i put an alert in, i get "undefined". Any ideas?

Comment: You should check user agent and use `document.body.offsetHeight` (or `document.documentElement.offsetHeight`) for IE.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best answer I could come up with, I finally found this by accident on a very helpful site.

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 701) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/narrow.css");
    } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/medium.css");
    } else {
       $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/wide.css");
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

The site is: http://css-tricks.com/6206-resolution-specific-stylesheets/

The jQuery changes the browser css on the fly so if you re size your browser the css changes. It also works in all browsers.

Comment: +1 Good solution. It's using jQuery so it takes care of cross browser issues.

Answer (score 0):

In [supporting browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20queries), you can use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) (specifically the [height media feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#height)).

Comment: From the section I linked to: "Accepts min/max prefixes: yes", so just use `max-height` or `min-height`

Answer (score 0):

You can use media Queries, as Quentin said. But, I think you already have the n css files and want to select one of them on fly. Just use something like this in your document head.

```
<script language="text/javascript">
if (screen.width == 640) {
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="640.css">');
}
else if (screen.width == 800) {
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="800.css">');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Screen height and browser height are different things.

Comment: Apologies. You are right. Use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight instead of screen.width and screen.height. Or in jQuery $(window).width() and $(window).height();